# Adding a temporary field in a class, just to aid development?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I was wondering is it possible with a .Net custom type to add a temporary field just for the life of object. I don't mean to add a field in POCO class that will be permanently, rather I was thinking something temporary. For example consider a person class having 3 fields:

```
Id int
Name string
Status string
```

Just while working I need to stored Old Status. I dont want a permanent field something that can aid development.

Comment: "While working" - you mean while refactoring code? Or while the code is working at runtime?

Comment: @Blorgbeard  I mean while coding and please also guide if it is possible on runtime.

Comment: But a field is just for the life of an object.

Comment: @Blam, agreed. But I dont want to code a new field. Something just temporary to aid development.

Comment: So just create the field and delete it when you've finished?

Comment: Just how do you expect to reference it in a development environment if it is not a field?   How is you code supposed to know if it is operating in a development versus a production environment?

Comment: You can't "add a temporary field" to an object only for development without modifying the object itself. If you need to store the "old status", you'll need to either add it to the object or store it in a variable in your code.

Comment: Guys, I think it's perfectly clear what he's asking and I think that  Alexei's answer is pretty good.

Comment: By the way I did not get why this question is down voted. Sorry to say it looks like these guys have very limited thinking. If they think something is not possible, they dont know or dislike they just start down voting or requesting to close it.

Comment: You were downvoted because your question is unclear (same reason people are voting to close it).

Comment: I cant understand how some one in IT can ignore possibilities and can image what he or she knows is final.

Comment: @user576510 noone is "ignoring possibilities" - we just don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: I think it's quite obvious, he wants to temporarily add a field to a class and there are indeed ways of doing that. The only problem I have is the 'why' aspect of it, but that's not the question being asked; indeed the question being asked is a good way of exploring the possibilities of IOC/DI, Polymorphism and Compiler conditionals; I should say that that is a very valid topic for this site and is bound to help others.

Comment: @Blorgbeard that is what my point is. You just did not understood and that is why down voted, rather one should ask if something is not clear. I will say this is very pessimistic  approach. Question looks clear that is why it got a answer and some comments on solution.

Comment: @RussC it's not clear what he means by "temporary". "For the life of the object" describes all fields; then he says "while coding, but also guide for runtime" - I have no idea what he wants at this point.

Comment: @user576510 it's up to you to make your question clear. Unclear questions get put on hold. If you edit your question, it's likely to be reopened.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I have got the answer with same statement. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: @user576510 OK, I'm glad someone was able to correctly understand your question - you will get *more* help if you put more effort in next time though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can derive new "debug only" version of the class and add new fields there. If you use some sort of factory or dependency injection framework to construct objects you should be able to do that at run time.

```
class DebugWrapper : MyPlainClass
{
     public string AdditionalData {get;set;}
}
```

One more option is to use `#if DEBUG` to add fields for debug builds. May work, but you run risk of testing code that you never give to others - so try to not go this route:

```
class MyPlainClass
{
    // normal fields
#if DEBUG
         public string AdditionalData {get;set;}
#endif
}
```

Comment: I like this answer; another option is to consider an IOC container, in debug mode, you can inject your amended class and in release, us the tradition container. As long as the code that access the debug additions, resides in the debug version of the class then all will be well.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, IOC is (in this instance) precisely the same as Dependancy injection; StructureMap is a good place to start.